# Transactional Replication from Copy Only Backup

Tags: sql-server, replication, sql-server-2016, transactional-replication

Is it possible to use a copy only backup when initializing a subscriber from a backup?

I've been trying it but getting all kinds of issues with:

- Trying to update records that don't exist
- Inserting records that already exist

Steps taken:

1. Created a pull publication (live server)
2. Created a copy only full backup
3. Restored backup on reporting server
4. Created a pull subscription from backup (live server)
5. Created procedures on reporting server from the result of sp_scriptpublicationcustomprocs
6. Created a pull subscription on subscriber (reporting server)

Example error: The row was not found at the Subscriber when applying the replicated UPDATE command for Table '[dbo].[table]' with Primary Key(s): [table_id] = 1234

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It'd be helpful to see a repro script or at the very least what you've done so far and the errors that occur.

Comment: And there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Updated with steps taken and example error.